# How to instantiate inner classes in one step in Scala?

Tags: java, class, scala, syntax, inner-classes

Consider this code:

```
class Outer {
  class Inner
}
```

In Java it would be possible to create an instance of `Inner` with:

```
Outer.Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner();
```

I know I can write this in Scala:

```
val outer = new Outer
val inner = new outer.Inner
```

But I wonder if it is possible to express the same without the assignment to `outer`.

Both

```
new Outer.new Inner
```

and

```
new (new Outer).Inner
```

are not accepted by the compiler.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, I doubt that the instantiation in one go is any meaningful -- you are like throwing away the `Outer` instance, keeping no reference to it. Makes me wonder, if you weren't thinking of a Java static inner class, like

```
public class Outer() {
   public static class Inner() {}
}
```

which in Scala would translate to `Inner` being an inner class of `Outer`'s *companion* object:

```
object Outer {
    class Inner
}

new Outer.Inner
```

If you really want an inner *dependent* class, and you just want more convenient syntax for instantiating it, you could add a companion object *for it*:

```
class Outer {
   object Inner {
      def apply() = new Inner()
   }
   class Inner
}

new Outer().Inner()
```

Comment: Ah the `apply` trick is cool. I was more or less interested in the syntax, e. g. if this is really something impossible in Scala ... I guess this is like PHP's restriction that array elements needed to be assigned before use.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
(new Outer() { def apply() = new Inner()})()
```

or

```scala
(new Outer() { val inner = new Inner()}).conditionObject
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have class declared like this:

```
class Outer {
  class Inner
}
```

then you need to instantiate outer class first and then instantiate inner class as following:

```
val outerTest = new Outer()
val innerTest = new outerTest.Inner()
```

now you can call inner class methods from using innerTest variable.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
it("Instantiate inner java class in scala") {
  val outer: Outer = new Outer()
  val inner = new outer.Inner("","")

}
```

Comment: But the OP specifically asks, _"...if it is possible to express the same without the assignment to `outer`."_